# Get data from arraylist of Structs, then inserting more data into other elements of the struct

Tags: c#, struct

I have an Arraylist of Structs called `tag` (shown below) and I can successfully import data into the structure. (The data shows up correctly when I debug.)

How can I access the data and write it to other elements in the structure?

```
struct tag 
{
    public string name;
    public string type;
    public string rack;
        public string card;
        public string channel;
        public string data;
        public string fault;
};

ArrayList TagList = new ArrayList();

importTag.name = "aName";
importTag.type = "atype";
importTag.rack = "arack";
importTag.card = "acard";
importTag.channel "achannel";
TagList.Add(importTag);

foreach (tag t in TagList){
    //tasty stuff in here
    //
}
```

Comment: Was not a very precise question...

Comment: Use `List<tag>` instead of `ArrayList` and don't use mutable structs. Use classes if you want to mutate the data in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `struct` here in the first place.  To being with, mutable structs are evil.  When you have a mutable struct you end up [mutating](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039854/1159478) a [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039828/1159478) of the [value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039931/1159478) instead of the value itself, so the code looks sensible, but doesn't actually work.  This is why structs should virtually always be immutable.

Next, your struct doesn't represent a single value; if you're making a struct, it should represent a singular logical value.

You also shouldn't use a struct if it's large; your struct is *quite* large.  This means all of that data is constantly being copied around.

You also shouldn't use a `struct` when it'll be boxed often, and you're boxing the structs that you're using.

You should use a `class` instead.  If you change your code to use a `class` rather than a `struct`, and also use a `List` instead of an `ArrayList` to leverage generics, then *after that* your code can become:

```
foreach(tag t in tagList)
{
    t.name = "new name";
}
```

If you insist on using a `struct` despite the fact that it violates *all* of the guidelines for when to use a struct then you'll need to create a new struct based on the new and old values and assign that new struct to the list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tagList.Count; i++)
{
    tagList[i] = new tag
    {
        name = "new name",
        type = tagList[i].type,
        rack = tagList[i].rack,
        card = tagList[i].card,
        channel = tagList[i].channel,
        data = tagList[i].data,
        fault = tagList[i].fault,
    };
}
```

Comment: I have tried changing the arraylist to a list with the code provided but my compiler is now telling me that it doesn't exist in the current context where the arraylist worked before in the same position.  I have added collections.generic etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating collection of same data then use strictly typed collections like List

```
List<tag> tagList = new List<tag>();
```

And because you are using ArrayList it returns each 'tag' as object so you need to do casting but if you are using above approach you can access list elements like this :

```
foreach(tag t in tagList)
{
    t.name = "your data";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code you're suggesting results in mutating a copy of the value, not the value in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `ArrayList` with structs.  If you use `List<tag>` rather than `ArrayList`, then you can modify items in the struct using:

```
List<tag> myList;

for (int i=0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
  var temp = myList[i];
  temp.card = "New value";
  myList[i] = temp;
}
```

If you don't mind using an array and managing the size yourself, then you can do something like:

```
tag[] myTags = new tag[16];
int myTagsCount;

void AddTag(tag newTag)
{
  if (myTagsCount >= myTags.Length)
    Array.Resize(ref myTags, myTagsCount*2);
  myTags[myTagsCount++] = newTag;
}

... and then when you want to modify each tag:

for (int i=0; i < myTags.Length; i++)
{
  myTags[i].card = "New Value";  // Arrays allow efficient in-place modification of structures
}
```

Note that if you use mutable class instead of a structure, some operations will be more convenient *but* you need to make sure that you never store into any collection which is supposed to hold tag values any reference to a tag which might be modified elsewhere.  Immutable classes will make sharing data a little easier and more efficient, but the only way to change what's encapsulated within a field or collection member will be to replace it with an entirely new object instance.  Structures often represent a very useful compromise.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but, do you what to do this?

```
foreach (tag t in TagList){
    t.name = "My New Name";
}
```

Comment: Of course you are using a struct. If you want to edit the references you have to use class instead.